# Redirect to a newpage and execute a function with arguments from the current page

Tags: php, jquery

How to get a function to get invoked in another page from the current page using query string.
* The point is this i have 2 select boxes and i want to redirect to a new page with a functionm executed on loading itself. 
* I have arguments for that function from the select box contents. How is that possible.

Basically....

1- Redirect to a new webpage on button click  ( Done with window.location )
2- Pass two arguments in the query string ( passed like mypage?value1&value2 )

3- Using the arguments , the new page gets loaded with that function call. ( dont know )
4- The select box contents should be loaded with the previous values ( dont know )

Comment: please explain briefly

Comment: i couldnt add the link perfectly , please check the link

Comment: @ vikram sharma: please check my updated question

Comment: i am checking.......

Answer (score 0):

if you submit the form to a new page you can access the submitted value in the new page by its id. if you want to trigger a form submit via javascript you can use this jquery code :

```
    jQuery(function(){
          jQuery("#subm1").click();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I got this right, but my suggestion is;

```
<select onchange="myFunction(this.value)">
<option>bla bla</option>
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction(value){
document.cookie= "value="+value;
window.location ="newPage.php";

}
</script>
```

or

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction(value){
window.location="newPage.php?value="+value;
}
</script>
```